# Python - Syntax error occurring on discord token

Tags: python, syntax, discord, token

I am rusty with Python as a whole but am completely new to anything as advanced as writing code for discord bots, up until now loading the token has worked but since implementing some code to test for a Wikipedia search function, it seems to cause a syntax error

My code looks like this:

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('Token')
```

The syntax error occurs on the last line and I have tried using `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` as well.

If it helps this is the error I'm getting

```
File "main.py", line 56
    load_dotenv('Token')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Edit - here is my code for main.py (The error now points to line 5 because I moved the token)**

```
import discord
import os
import wikipedia

#from dotenv import load_dotenv('Token')

client = discord.Client()

def wiki_summary(arg):
  definition = wikipedia.summary(arg, sentences=1, chars=100, auto_suggest=True, redirect=True)
  return definition



@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
  if message.content.startswith('$hi'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
  if message.content.startswith('$hey'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    
  if message.content.startswith('$hru'):
    await message.channel.send('I am just a bot contained to my creators tiny brain, unfortuantely I do not have emotions :(')

  if message.content.startswith('$who is your creator?'):
    await message.channel.send('If I told you, Id have to kill you...\nIts Liam')
  if message.content.startswith('$who is your creator'):
    await message.channel.send('If I told you, Id have to kill you ...\nIts Liam')
  if message.content.startswith('$whos your creator'):
    await message.channel.send('If I told you, Id have to kill you...\n Its Liam')
  if message.content.startswith('$whos your creator?'):
    await message.channel.send('If I told you, Id have to kill you...\n Its Liam')
  if message.content.startswith('$test'):
    await message.channel.send('nope')


  if message.content.startswith('$starship') and ('$Starship'):
    await message.channel.send('The Starship system is a fully reusable, two‑stage‑to‑orbit super heavy‑lift launch vehicle under development by SpaceX.[11] The system is composed of a booster stage named Super Heavy, and a second stage, also called Starship. Read more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship')
        
  if message.content.startswith('$SLS'):
    await message.channel.send('The Space Launch System (SLS) is an American Space Shuttle-derived super heavy-lift expendable launch vehicle, which has been under development by NASA in the United States since its announcement in 2011. Read more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Launch_System')
  if message.content.startswith('$sls'):
    await message.channel.send('The Space Launch System (SLS) is an American Space Shuttle-derived super heavy-lift expendable launch vehicle, which has been under development by NASA in the United States since its announcement in 2011. Read more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Launch_System')

  if message.content.startswith('!define'):
    words = message.content.split()
    important_words = words[1:]
    await client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words))

    words = message.content.split()
    important_words = words[1:]

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))  

#load_dotenv('Token')
```

Comment: pls post the code from main.py. the error message says that you have syntax error on line 56 of main.py.

Comment: @simpleApp I have updated the post with the code

Comment: in line `client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words)` one ) missing. pls put it. so it will be like :) - `await client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words))`

Comment: @simpleApp I have made that change but the syntax error is on line 5 which is `from .env import load_.env('Token')`

Comment: may I know which documentation you are following? are you referring [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Comment: @simpleApp I seem to have fixed the token issue by using `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` but now I have a TabError with `words = message.content.split()
important_words = words[1:]` as I moved it down because of message being undefined

Comment: If you have updated the code on your end, it might help to update it in your question as well, so we can see the issue. 

A TabError means you used a mix of spaces and tabs for the indentation.

You cannot do that in Python, it has very strict whitespace rules. You must either pick spaces or tabs for your indentation, and it needs to be a consistent number of spaces for each level of indentation.

Comment: @tsalaroth Thanks for the reminder, the code in the question has been updated :)

Answer (score 0):

in line client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words) one ) missing. pls put it. so it will be like -

`await client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words))`

or simple use case is:
you have file .env with data:

```
DOMAIN=example.org
ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@${DOMAIN}
ROOT_URL=${DOMAIN}/app
```

now to get the config,

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values
config = dotenv_values(".env") 
# show values
for each_conf in config:
    print(f"{each_conf} : {config[each_conf]}")
```

and output is as follows, and can take it forward from here.

```
DOMAIN : example.org
ADMIN_EMAIL : admin@example.org
ROOT_URL : example.org/app
```